# Cannot write the event log when the app runs on windows server 2012 from server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I upgrade my app which worked fine on Windows Server 2008(32 bit) from framework 3.5 to 4.5 for Windows Server 2012(64 bit). In the app, there is third party component runs on 32 bit. We cannot upgrade it because the supplier has no plans to update it. Therefore my app platform target is set for any CPU but Prefer 32-bit on my project property. All function is work except writing the event log. Would anyone provide suggestion to deal with this issue? Thank in advance.

There is my code to write the event log.

```
private static void RecordEventLog(string sMessage, EventLogEntryType ErrorType)
    {
        string source = "Testing App";
        string logName = "Application";
        string machineName = ".";
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source, machineName))
        {
            EventSourceCreationData sourceData = new EventSourceCreationData(source, logName);
            sourceData.MachineName = machineName;
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(sourceData);
        }
        new EventLog(logName, machineName, source).WriteEntry(sMessage, ErrorType);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be the rights to create the event source - I can't see why 32 vs 64-bit would make a difference.  You may have to run the app with admin privileges (at least the first time) to create the event source.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a.aspx):

> To create an event source in Windows Vista and later or Windows Server
>   2003, you must have administrative privileges.
>
> The reason for this requirement is that all event logs, including
>   security, must be searched to determine whether the event source is
>   unique. Starting with Windows Vista, users do not have permission to
>   access the security log; therefore, a SecurityException is thrown.
>
> In Windows Vista and later, User Account Control (UAC) determines the
>   privileges of a user. If you are a member of the Built-in
>   Administrators group, you are assigned two run-time access tokens: a
>   standard user access token and an administrator access token. By
>   default, you are in the standard user role. To execute the code that
>   accesses the security log, you must first elevate your privileges from
>   standard user to administrator. **You can do this when you start an
>   application by right-clicking the application icon and indicating that
>   you want to run as an administrator.**